# Can the recursion $x_{n+1} = 3{(x_n)}^2+2$ with $x_0 = 2$, be solved?

Tags: recurrence-relations

This can be solved computationally, but is there an analytical solution? I've tried to build a solution and it wasn't pretty.
$$x_{n+1} = 3{(x_n)}^2+2 \qquad x_0 = 2$$

Comment: The recursion $$z\mapsto z^2+c$$ is well known to have no analytical solution in general (some entire books with nice images have been written on the subject).